# ErrorStateMatcher to validate if password == confirmPassword doesn't works correctly

Tags: html, angular, validation, angular-material, angular6

My Problem:
i implemented an ErrorStateMatcher in Angular, to validate if the entered password in a form is the same as the confirmPassword.
It works, but the problem is, that the confirmPassword field is shown red till the form is completely filled.

the bottom right field isn't filled here:
[image]

when everything is filled the confirmPassword field isn't red anymore:
[image]

ErrorStateMatcher:

```
    export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(
    control: FormControl | null,
    form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null
  ): boolean {
    const invalidCtrl = !!(control && control.invalid && control.parent.dirty);
    const invalidParent = !!(
      control &&
      control.parent &&
      control.parent.invalid &&
      control.parent.dirty
    );
    return invalidCtrl || invalidParent;
  }
}
```

component.ts:

```
export class AdminpanelComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private ts: TableService,
    private us: UserService,
    private as: AdminpanelService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        email: new FormControl(
          "",
          Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            ValidationService.emailValidator
          ])
        ),
        password: new FormControl(
          "",
          Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
              ValidationService.passwordValidator
          ])
        ),
        confirmPassword: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
        firstName: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
        lastName: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
        permission: new FormControl("", Validators.required)
      },
      { validator: this.checkPasswords }
    );
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
userList: UserRegister[] = [];
  userRegister!: UserRegister;

  submitUser() {
    this.userRegister = Object.assign({}, this.registerForm.value);
    this.us.registerUser(this.userRegister);
    this.userList.push(this.userRegister);
  }
  get form() {
    return this.registerForm.controls;
  }
  checkPasswords(group: FormGroup) {
    let pass = group.controls.password.value;
    let confirmPass = group.controls.confirmPassword.value;
    return pass === confirmPass ? null : { notSame: true };
  }
}
```

component.html:

```
      <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon">person_add</mat-icon>
          Neuer Benutzer
        </ng-template>

        <form [formGroup]="registerForm" class="usercreation-form" (ngSubmit)="submitUser()">
          <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input id="firstName" matInput placeholder="Vorname" formControlName="firstName" required>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('required')">
                    Please enter your first name
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </td>
              <td>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="lastName" required>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('required')">
                    Please enter your last name
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Passwort" formControlName="password">
                  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('required', 'password')">
                    Please enter your password
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </td>
              <td>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Passwort bestätigen" formControlName="confirmPassword"
                    [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
                  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.hasError('required', 'notSame')">
                    Passwords do not match
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>

          <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input id="email" type="email" matInput placeholder="Email" formControlName="email" required>
                  <mat-error>
                    wrong email format
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </td>
              <td>
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <mat-select placeholder="Berechtigung" formControlName="permission">
                    <mat-option value="user">Benutzer</mat-option>
                    <mat-option value="admin">Administrator</mat-option>
                  </mat-select>
                  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm.controls['permission'].hasError('required') && registerForm.controls['permission'].pristine">
                    please choose the permission
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <button type="submit" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid">submit</button>
        </form>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-tab>
```

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed `MyErrorStateMatcher` to this and now it works:

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const invalidParent = !!(
      control
      && control.parent
      && control.parent.invalid
      && control.parent.dirty
      && control.parent.hasError('notSame'));
    return (invalidParent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes :
`*ngIf="registerForm.hasError('required', 'password')"` to `*ngIf="registerForm['controls'].password.hasError('required', 'password')"`

```
               <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                  <input type="password" matInput placeholder="Passwort" formControlName="password">
                  <mat-error *ngIf="registerForm['controls'].password.hasError('required', 'password')">
                    Please enter your password
                  </mat-error>
                </mat-form-field>
```

Do the same for `confirmPassword`

Comment: i did, unfortunately still the same behavior.

Comment: Do the same for `confirmPassword` and other controls as well

Comment: i did, unfortunately still the same behavior :(
"<mat-error *ngIf="registerForm['controls'].password.hasError('required', 'password')">"
"<mat-error *ngIf="registerForm['controls'].confirmPassword.hasError('required', 'password', 'notSame')">"